Surjectivity & Injectivity of the natural map $M \otimes \prod_{i \in I} N_i \rightarrow \prod_{i \in I} (M \otimes N_i)$
I am aware that the tensor product commutes with direct sums, and that it does not, in general, commute with direct products. I have sketched a proof for the direct sum case, but my argument showing the isomorphism relies on the finite support property of the direct sum for both the injectivity and surjectivity of the map.
I suspect that either injectivity or surjectivity (but not both!) is not actually reliant on the fact that I am taking sums as opposed to products.
Here's what I have so far:
Using the map $m \otimes [(n_i)_{i \in I}] \mapsto (m \otimes n_i)_{i \in I}$, I argue for injectivity/surjectivity as follows:
Injectivity:
Suppose $m \otimes (n_i)_{i \in I} \mapsto (0 \otimes 0)_{i \in I}$. We may write
$$
m \otimes (n_i) = m \otimes \left(\iota_{i_1}(n_{i_1}) + \dots + \iota_{i_k}(n_{i_k}) \right)
=m \otimes \iota_{i_1}(n_{i_1}) + \dots + m \otimes \iota_{i_k}(n_{i_k})
$$
Where $\iota_{i}$ is the natural injection $N_{i} \rightarrow^{\iota} \bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i $.
Then, each of the above terms on the far right must vanish since we have that $m \otimes n_{i_j} = 0$ for each $j$. Therefore $m \otimes (n_i) = 0$ as desired.
Establishing this for pure tensors will let us set up an induction which lets us show injectivity (I omit the details because they are messy and unhelpful).
Surjectivity:
Let $(m_i \otimes n_i) \in \bigoplus_{i \in I} (M \otimes N_i)$.
By the finite support, we can find $m_{i_j}, n_{i_j}$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$ (for some finite $k$) where $m_{i_1} \otimes \iota_{i_1}(n_{i_1}) + \dots + m_{i_k} \otimes \iota_{i_k}(n_{i_k}) \mapsto (m_i \otimes n_i)_{i \in I}$, where we again use the finite support of $(m_i \otimes n_i)_{i \in I}$ in an essential way.
To reiterate, my issue is that I would expect either injectivity or surjectivity of this natural mapping to carry over to the direct product situation, whereas my proof relies on the finiteness for both. Is this the case? If so, what is a proof?

It is not in general enough to show that none of the generators maps to zero to prove injectivity. I don't think your proof of that is complete as written. Note that not all elements of $M\otimes M'$ are pure tensors: the general element is a sum of tensors. It suffices for surjectivity because a morphism is surjective if and only if every generator of the codomain lies in the image.

Good catch, I should have added a further comment about that. The idea is essentially the same, just messier once you're setting up the induction.

The answer here shows that the map $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\prod_k(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})\to \prod_k(\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})$ is not generally injective (the left hand side is nontrivial, the right hand side is trivial). In the comments, it is noted that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\prod\mathbb{Z}\to\prod(\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Z})$ is not surjective, because the right hand  side includes elements with arbitrarily large denominator. So neither injectivity nor surjectivity needs to hold for the direct product.

If that question answers your query, then I will close this question as a duplicate. If not, please specify what still remains unaddressed.

This answers my query. Thank you.
